# How do i send form data to php using fetch in nativescript?

Tags: php, nativescript, fetch-api

I'm trying to do a signup form in my nativescript app, i'm using fetch api to POST the data. But right now it just populates the database without actually uploading the data. this is what i've tried

**JS**

```
const phpData = {
                email: "user@nativescript.org",
                password: "password",
                name: "Adekunle Adeyeye",
                number: "07019888741",
            }
            /*email = viewModel.getViewById("email").value;
            password = viewModel.getViewById("password").value;
            name = viewModel.getViewById("name").value;
            number = viewModel.getViewById("number").value;*/

            fetch("https://goodsbuy.000webhostapp.com/register.php", {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(phpData),
                headers:{
                    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
            .then((phpData) => {
                console.log('Success:', phpData);
                this.set("processing", false);
                Toast.makeText("Successful").show();
                this.isLoggingIn = true;
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                this.set("processing", false);
                Toast.makeText("Account Already exists").show();
                this.isLoggingIn = false;
              });
```

**PHP**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
      $sql = "INSERT INTO comedyapp(`name`, `email`, `number`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number', '$password')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo '{"items":'. json_encode('Good') .'}'; 
        } else {
            echo '{"items":'. json_encode('Bad') .'}';
        }
```

Please assist me.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: @treyBake how? Just for my knowledge.

Comment: If you're passing the data as stringified json in the body, you might need to access the data using: `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` and then run  `$params = json_decode($data, true);` to turn the json into an array.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) :)

Comment: thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @treyBake THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
```

with

```
extract(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true));
```

it will automatically declares the variables.

Comment: It's way better to keep the array as an array in one variable than using `extract()`. Specially when the data comes from the front end.

Comment: yes, agree with your comment. will look forward to it.

Comment: Like the documentation for [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) says: _"Warning
Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES)."_ (that includes post data)

Comment: thank you very much @MagnusEriksson. will definitely keep it in mind.